# Get row values only if a particular column's value does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have two tables in my database `students`:

**GRADE_REPORT:**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+
|StudentNo       | SectionId   | Grade| 
+----------------+-------------+------+
| 11             | 85          | B    |     
| 17             | 112         | B    |
| 17             | 119         | C    |     
| 17             | 135         | A    |
| 8              | 85)         | A    |     
| 8              | 92          | A    |
+----------------+-------------+------+
```

**STUDENT:**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+--------+----------------+
| StudentNumber  | name        | Classification| DepartmentName |
+----------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 17             | Bill Smith  | 1             |      CS        |       
| 8              | Bob Brown   | 2             |      CS        |
| 11             | Nick Fiener | 4             |      MATH      |       
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+---------+
```

I am trying to find retrieve the student number, name and major departments of all students who **do** not have any grade A in any of their courses. So I am expecting the following when I run the query:

```
+----------------+-------------+----------------+
| StudentNumber  | name        | DepartmentName |
+----------------+-------------+----------------+
| 11             | Nick Fiener | MATH           |
```

This is my statement so far:

```
SELECT students.STUDENT.StudentNumber, students.STUDENT.name,
  students.STUDENT.DepartmentName 
FROM students.GRADE_REPORT
INNER JOIN students.STUDENT 
ON students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo = students.STUDENT.StudentNumber
WHERE 
( (students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "B"  
   OR 
   students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "C" ) 
   AND  students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade != "A")  
GROUP BY students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo;
```

EDITED:

```
SELECT students.STUDENT.StudentNumber, students.STUDENT.name, students.STUDENT.DepartmentName 
    FROM students.STUDENT S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo
                                                    FROM students.GRADE_REPORT gr
                                                        WHERE gr.StudentNo = S.StudentNumber
                                                            AND gr.Grade = "A");
```

Comment: I modified the code according to Mr. gordon's instruction (please see the post). However I am getting an error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'students.STUDENT.StudentNumber' in 'field list'`? Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: replace `students.STUDENT.StudentNumber` to `s.studentnumber` and all others accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from grade_report gr
                  where gr.student_no = s.student_no and gr.grade = 'A'
                 );
```

Comment: I modified the code according your instruction (please see the post). However I am getting an error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'students.STUDENT.StudentNumber' in 'field list'`? Can you tell me why?

Comment: @lovesTrumpsHate . . . There is no `students.STUDENT.studentNumber` in this query.  Use the table alias.